# Blueimp jQuery File Upload Audio/Video Preview

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

After some googling, I cant find an example of using the audio & video preview extensions of the jQuery file upload plugin.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Has anyone used these who can provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 6):

you just have to add the `jquery.fileupload-video` file when you use the plugin for upload your videos. This is how I use it

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = YourURL+"public/server/php/";

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 40000000, // 40 MB
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 300,
        previewMaxHeight: 200,
        previewCrop: true,
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div class="col-md-3 videopreview" />').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>');
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link).append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
                $( "#filesHidden" ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="' + file.name + '">' );
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');

});
```

Also remember to add the following

- jquery.ui.widget.js
- load-image.min.js
- jquery.iframe-transport.js
- jquery.fileupload.js
- jquery.fileupload-validate-es_ES.js //This is just for the language
- jquery.fileupload.css

Comment: I am getting a min_file_size error while uploading video. what is it?

Comment: @AbelD You have to check your php.ini and look for the min file size or upuload file size

Comment: i want to upload both audio/video.. how will i separate the upload functions?

Comment: i suggest that you use different `class` one for audio and other for video, and then add the options according to what you want.